# in storm 1.2.2 deployment, ui is stuck in "loading summary"

Tags: deployment, apache-storm

I tried to deploy apache storm for a streaming program development. 4 servers for 1 nimbus/ui and 3 supervisors. After all setup, nimbus/ui/supervisors are launched without errors/exceptions reported in logs. But when access to ui via browser, the page is stuck in a spinning prompted "loading summary" like for ever.

All processes are killed and zookeeper node "/storm" and storm data folder are cleared. Still stuck on ui after restart the cluster.

Also switched to lower rev 1.1.3, still same problem, looks like not a bug specific to rev, more like a bug relevant to my setting. But really confusing to figure out. Anyone familiar with storm can help me on this?[image]

Comment: I think you should look in logs/access-ui.log and logs/access-web-ui.log to see if there are errors listed there. Otherwise, try opening your browser's dev tools, and check if any requests are failing.

Comment: hi Rohde, thanks for your reply, I used another browser then not stuck anymore. But I am blocked on another issue days that supervisor always can't connect to nimbus specified in yaml, always connect to local host and fail. details are in another of my posts, can you pls. help give some comments?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51945443/storm-1-2-2-supervisor-also-take-localhost-as-nimbus-and-cant-connect-to-it-al