# Storm 1.2.2 Supervisor also take localhost as nimbus and can't connect to it, although nimbus is in another server and already specified in storm.yaml

Tags: apache-storm

problem is just as titled, no errors printed in supervisor logs after cluster is started. whenever a jar is submitted, error is reported in supervistors' log that fail to connect localhost nimbus.

1, here is my yaml:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
    - "beta-hbase02"
    - "beta-hbase03"
    - "beta-hbase04"
storm.zookeeper.root: "/storm"
nibus.seeds: ["beta-hbase01"]
storm.local.dir: "/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/apache-storm/storm/data"
supervisor.slots.ports:
    - 6800
    - 6801
    - 6802
    - 6803
ui.port: 8686
storm.log.dir: "/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/apache-storm/logs"
worker.childopts: "-Xmx1024m"
nimbus.childopts: "-Xmx2048m"
```

2, here is the error in supervisor.log, nother in access-supervisor.log

```
2018-08-21 17:10:23.643 o.a.s.l.AsyncLocalizer Async Localizer [WARN] Caught Exception While Downloading (rethrowing)... 
org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [localhost]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:120) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:66) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:58) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.blobstore.NimbusBlobStore.prepare(NimbusBlobStore.java:268) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.getClientBlobStoreForSupervisor(Utils.java:539) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.localizer.AsyncLocalizer$DownloadBaseBlobsDistributed.downloadBaseBlobs(AsyncLocalizer.java:121) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.localizer.AsyncLocalizer$DownloadBaseBlobsDistributed.call(AsyncLocalizer.java:148) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.localizer.AsyncLocalizer$DownloadBaseBlobsDistributed.call(AsyncLocalizer.java:101) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_171]
```

Comment: also I changed the nimbus from host name to IP, still not work. any yaml change, also have all nimbus/supervisor/ui killed and local/data folder and /storm node in zookeeper are emptied.

Comment: add zookeeper port, still no luck. storm.zookeeper.port: 2181

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled "nimbus.seeds".

Comment: hi stig, I have another storm/trident built function problem, can you pls. check? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52051584/how-to-use-storm-trident-builtin-min-with-hbase-state-mapper

Comment: hi stig, sorry to trouble you, really appreciate if you can help check these 2 new questions as well:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52058637/possible-to-have-more-than-1-cols-agged-and-mapped-to-hbase-for-storm-trident

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52058741/possible-to-use-counter-in-double-type-for-storm-hbase-state-mapper-trident

Comment: You don't need to write here. I check the apache-storm tag once in a while to see if there are any questions I can answer. I'm not familiar enough with HBase to answer your questions. You might have more luck trying the storm-user mailing list (https://storm.apache.org/getting-help.html)